# How to write two CSS files: with and without sourcemap

Tags: css, automation, sass, gulp, source-maps

I need to have two merged CSS files in one directory - one with sourcemap and another without. What I tried for example is something like this :

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
.pipe(concat('xxx.dev.min.css'))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write())
.pipe(gulp.dest(cssDir))
.pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps:true}))
.pipe(concat('xxx.min.css'))
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('/dev/null', {addComment: false}))
.pipe(gulp.dest(cssDir))
```

All my trying resulted in either both files having a sourcemap, both not having a sourcemap or one having sourcemap based on another, not on original files.

Can this be achieved with only gulp-sourcemaps and how and if not, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src(['js/one.css', 'js/two.css'])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('withoutSourcemap.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(concat('withSourcemap.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This sends the concatenated `withoutSourcemap.css` to the destination directory before source mappings have been generated. We then basically just rename the file to `withSourcemap.css`. Only after all that is the source map written to the stream and sent to the destination directory.

**EDIT:** This is the generated `withSourcemap.css` in my case:

```
.one { color:red; }

.two { color:blue; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIm9uZS5jc3MiLCJ0d28uY3NzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBO0FBQ0E7QUNEQTtBQUNBIiwiZmlsZSI6IndpdGhTb3VyY2VtYXAuY3NzIiwic291cmNlc0NvbnRlbnQiOlsiLm9uZSB7IGNvbG9yOnJlZDsgfVxuIiwiLnR3byB7IGNvbG9yOmJsdWU7IH1cbiJdLCJzb3VyY2VSb290IjoiL3NvdXJjZS8ifQ== */
```

Base64-decoding the embedded source map yields the following:

```
{"version":3,"sources":["one.css","two.css"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;AACA;ACDA;AACA","file":"withSourcemap.css","sourcesContent":[".one { color:red; }\n",".two { color:blue; }\n"],"sourceRoot":"/source/"}
```

Comment: Nice try, but this would create a sourcemapin withSourcemap.js based on withoutSourcemap.js, not based on js/one.js and js/two.js because the 2 files are already merged in the stream :) I actually had it set up like this and thought it's working also.

Comment: Huh? The generated source map has `"sources":["one.css","two.css"]` not `"sources":["withoutSourcemap.css"]` (see my edit above), which should mean that it's based on `one.css` and `two.css` not `withoutSourcemap.css`. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: It actually worked well, my bad. I had it wrong before. Thanks ;)